# Flutter Hot reloading not working in android studio(mac)

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

While working on mac machine I found that hot reloading not working in Android Studio. I don't know what's wrong :)

Here is the code which not reloading(I am changing the **Hello world** text to **Flutter Sample** text)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Demo Project"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: new Text("Hello World!!!")),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Please see this below video with the link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7viujcgv8w0mtr/hot_reload.mp4?dl=0

This not stop my development, But I am concerned why it is happening.

Comment: This is weird, it happened to me couple of times too. I closed everything, restarted the project and then it worked fine.

Comment: My question here a little out of the topic, did the some problem is happened when you're using **IntelliJ**?

Comment: I am not using IntelliJ, sorry.

Comment: My hot reload is working in Visual studio code, but not working in Android Studio, any one ?

Comment: I think the correct answer is Invin's; https://stackoverflow.com/a/61567821/5503625 You should mark it as accepted

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Flutter Documentation says "Hot reload loads code changes into the VM and re-builds the widget tree, preserving the app state; it *doesn’t rerun* **main**() or **initState**()"

So, it looks like if the app logic resides outside the **main method**, then Hot Reloading works. Try to refactor your app like below and then do **Restart** (green button). Any subsequent changes you make, will be **HOT RELOADED** when saved.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Demo Project"),
        ),
        body: Center(child: new Text("Hello World!!!")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Hot Reload will not work if you are adding new assets (like images, or medial files). In those cases you will have to restart the App.

Comment: This solves my problem. I am working with Flutter version 1.18.0-11.1.pre.

Comment: Glad, I could help

Comment: Big thanks! I doubt it's something to do with latest Flutter upgrade, only to find out your answer explains the culprit.

Comment: This is the correct solution, if hot reload doesn't work even when hot reload preferences are enabled.

Answer (score 21):

**Try This**

The solution on GitHub [Reloaded 0 of NNN libraries in Xms](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/450#issuecomment-631344162)

Android Studio uses IDEA to import files automatically, Like this

```
import 'file///F:/flutter_project/lib/home_page.dart';
```

Change it to

```
import 'package:flutter_project/home_page.dart';
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was just extracting the whole `MaterialApp` into it's own stateless `Widget`.

Before -

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text("Helloo"),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        )),
      ),
    ));
}
```

After -

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text("Helloo"),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Even VS Code complains if you are just defining your whole app inside main function.

Solved! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your code with a `StatefulWidget` like shown in the code below.
This might be confusing when watching old tutorials because it used to work without it on an earlier Flutter Version.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Demo Project"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: new Text("Hello World!!!")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The use of MaterialApp is not justified in this case. It can be just ```runApp(new myApp())``` in ```void main()```. If you use MaterialApp, then it will be in different uglish styling.

Comment: Moreover, I just checked and it also works with ```StatelessWidget```. So absolutely no reason to use ```StatefulWidget``` and ```MaterialApp```. Hotreload works with ```StatelessWidget```.

Answer (score 5):

in the terminal, run

`flutter doctor -v`

`flutter upgrade`

Also, try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` from Android studio menu

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart solved it for me. Thanks.

Comment: yes Invalidating caches fixes for me as well

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not mistaken, hot reload calls the build method of your widget, as the change you made weren't made inside a build method, it didn't change anything in the screen.

Try changing the texting inside the MyWidget Build method and see if it works.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Demo Project"),
      ),
      body: new MyWidget(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: new Text("Hello World!!!"));
  }
}
```

Comment: I had this problem once and closing android studio and reopening did the trick. @jitsm555.

Comment: This is the correct answer and great with explanation of how hot reload works.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, when I used the VSCode keymap plugin, the hot reloading on save did`nt work.
After I changed the keymap to IntelliJ keymap, the hot reloading on save worked properly.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe this was the thing causing this issue ;_;
Edit: Forgot to mention that it worked for me too

Comment: And it's been over a year without a fix :/

Answer (score 3):

A hot reload in android studio against vscode which is **Ctrl+S** is triggered by **Save All** or explicitly calling the hot reload

[image]
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=androidstudio

A workaround is to set **Ctrl+S** as the save all shortcut. Out of the box it's **Ctrl+K, S**, that's why you see other solution that is suggesting to reset your keymap to Intellij

[image]

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Put your code inside **stateless of stateful widge**t.
To make **HOT RELOAD** work code must be inside stateless of stateful widget.

Comment: Can you explain more with some example code?

Comment: Do you mean 'or' instead of 'of'?

Answer (score 2):

Hot reload stopped working suddenly in my project. Using **Android Studio** and **Windows**.

When moving files around, the Android Studio would refactor imports, which is neat. But it would use **absolute imports** (C://Users/Projects/.../file.dart) and that would break hot reload completely. Be careful when moving files.

Answer (score 1):

How to use Flutter Hot Reload in a StatelessWidget inside Android Studio 3.6.2 and Flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.9 on Linux ... inside main.dart file:

Make sure in Android Studio > File > settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > check "Perform hot reload on save"!!!

Use the code below -> change the 'Hello' -> save it -> see the hot reload result

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // StatelessWidget turns this class into a widget
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Text('Hello'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using VScode for flutter in Windows. Was facing same issue with hot reload. 
Updated Dart and Flutter package to latest version and luckily it started working.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was running `flutter run` from the Android Studio terminal instead of clicking the Play or Debug button to run my application.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve it you need to update flutter sdk.

Comment: how to update it? although I applied the command flutter upgrade and got everything is update 2 date.

Comment: Delete your flutter sdk. Download and extract the new from flutter.io website.

Answer (score 0):

This works if all else fails:
1. Close Android Studio and the Simulators

2. Delete Android Studio by opening the Finder, click Applications, right click on Android Studio and click Move to Trash
3. Remove Android files:
   $ cd ~/Library/Android
   $ rm -fr *
   $ cd
   $ rm -fr .android
4. Remove Java
   https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml
5. Install Java
6. Install and Launch Android Studio and accept the license agreements
   https://developer.android.com/studio/install

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your changes you made in main.dart file.
After that hot reload will work,
on visual studio select auto-save option
then it will work perfectly fine.

*Hot reload needs to save your files first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto android studio and click help and select check for updates
2. Now click on update button.
3. After restart goto plugins and reinstall the flutter plugin by uninstalling and reinstalling the pugins.

Answer (score 0):

These might cause because of too many codes and assets. Simply delete the app from the emulator and rerun it again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just deleted the old app from phone. Then run from Android Studio. Maybe i tried release app and don't delete after(can't remember exactly). In any case, it is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue with Flutter 1.22.6. But worked fine when I used `Cmd+S` instead of Hot Reload (lightning) button

Answer (score 0):

***There are following steps to resovle this issue***

1. Check the **import package** line it should be like
   *`packages: your file`* not *`file:///`*
2. use command `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` in your terminal / command promp

> NOTE: you have to use these command from your project root directory

Its work for me

Answer (score 0):

Hot reload works only out of the main method. If your is inside the main method try to make a class of stateless or stateful widgets and pass the name as a parameter to runApp()

Answer (score 0):

In my case, hot reload failed due to insufficient storage space on the emulator. I didn't get an error in the console until I stopped and tried to re-run the project. To get hot reload working in my case, I had to stop the emulator, and increase the storage capacity on the device, and re-run the project.

Answer (score -1):

I constantly have similar problems when there are new unapplied Mac OS updates. You can disable auto-updates or install updates from incoming notifications.

[image: mac os updates]

Answer (score -5):

This is what you're looking for

[image]
In File -> Settings -> Keymap, you should assign some key shortcut for that to happen. Default it will be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: The video on the question shows the hot reload happening, the flutter message, but nothing happening on the emulator, so it's not a shortcut issue.